# How powerful is a gnat?

Tags: mistborn

In the Mistborn Adventure Game, a person who is a *Misting* has their Powers level set at **Average**. However, a Misting who burns Aluminum has an effectively worthless power since it requires the ability to burn other metals to do anything at all. This is why they are called an **Aluminum Gnat**.

So say for some reason I want to play an Aluminum Misting, whose only power is the ability to burn off any ingested aluminum. Do I set his Powers level at **Average** and gain a non-existent stunt (there are no stunts for Aluminum), or do I set his Powers level at **Weak** since there is no practical application for being an Aluminum Misting?

Comment: Never heard of the game, but great out of context title.

Comment: @Canageek You should check it out! It's based on the Mistborn books by Brandon Sanderson. Really fun system of magic, the particular one referenced in question requires you to have metal in your stomach to be able to access said power.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As someone that's about to run a Mistborn game, I would allow someone to be an aluminum gnat to have "weak" powers. It's not technically following the rules (since as you point out, mistings are supposed to have "average" powers), but it seems like it would unnecessarily penalize the player to use their "average" slot on something that couldn't possibly help them.

Answer (score 5):

I think that it is worth pointing out that technically burning Aluminium uses up *all* metals in your system - not just the Aluminium.  It could, for example, be used to destroy metals that you have obtained from another PC or NPC - to deny them their use or other such creative strategies.  ;)

I would also frown upon allowing a player to select Weak as their power level to be an Aluminium (or Duralumin) Misting partially because it allows them to have higher Attributes or Standings, and because (as others have mentioned) they can gain other Allomantic or Feruchemical abilities via Heamalurgy - which would then make their 'Gnat' status no longer useful.

Comment: If the *PCs* are gaining abilities via hemalurgy then you probably have larger problems than incorrectly setting the power level of an aluminum Misting.

Comment: @ObliviousSage: ...although the books do give at least one potential backstory for a "good" character with hemalurgic augmentation. (Trying not to spoil too much, here.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen None of the good, or even debatable, characters *deliberately* empower themselves via hemalurgy. There's only one good-ish character who even really understands how hemalurgy is used.

Comment: @ObliviousSage - You say problems, I say ... plot potential.  :)

Comment: "Aluminium uses up all metals in your system - not just the Aluminium" - It does if you're a Mistborn. There's no supporting evidence that it'd do anything...plus simply swallowing their metal supplies yourself would make it impractical to recover during a fight (even if you couldn't burn it) so I'm not really sure how that'd be an advantage. And sure, gaining additional powers via Hemalurgy is a possibility, but at worst an Aluminum compounder can become immune to mental influences.

Comment: @Cthos - My reasoning for making that assertion about the effect of Aluminium is based on the following from the rules, page 339.

"Burning Aluminium instantly burns *consumes) all other metal stored in the Allomancer's system."

{And now I learn that [enter] also posts the comment...}

Comment: @Vecna Ah yes, but what does "Stored" mean to the allomancer? Metal reserves that he has access to, or the actual metal in the stomach. That's unclear to me based on the books and the published materials we have for the game. Like is it destroying the investure, or is it simply consuming the metals? Either way though, swallowing the metals is a pretty effective way to get rid of someone else's stores, Aluminum misting or no. What's the allomancer going to do? Cut open your stomach to recover the contents?

Comment: Well, some of the metals are poisonous if not burned up - at least in the book it's mentioned. Swallowing, say, copper isn't a good idea in RL, and it's implied it's harmful when not burned up. Still a niece use. Also, *technically*, aluminium could do more than just burn metals, but we don't know what yet. It might dispel other sorts of magic from the wider cosmere (multiverse of which Scadriel is part of).

Comment: @ObliviousSage, With the Wax and Wayne series, and other sources, we can see that Hemalurgy isn't bad, per se, only if used in the wrong way. For example, The Survivor of  the Flames, the lord Mistborn, Spook suggests using old allomancers to create spikes and power people, and I believe Sazed, as Harmony talks about using Hemalurgy for the greater good.